# ASP.Net - Hosting Web API source code without publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, publishing

Is there any way I can host a C#-based ASP.Net Web API project without publishing it?  It's a new project and I wish to be able to host the C# source code files directly.  That way every time there's an update, I can replace just the necessary C# code files instead of publishing the project and posting the dll file.

Note that I'm also using Entity Framework, in case that matters.

Comment: Your code needs to be hosted in a web server of some kind. You definitely need to compile it - you can't just host `.cs` files. I'm not sure what you mean by 'host the C# files directly' but maybe you mean run inside your own web server. Which is completely valid, but a bit of a security issue.

Comment: There's good reasons for having a publishing step. For example you only publish your app when it's free of bugs

Comment: I do have my own server space, and that's where I'm hosting the project.  I do understand that hosting published code would help ensure it's bug-free.  However, while we are still in the preliminary development phase, I was wondering if I could post code files for API instead and somehow compile pages at run-time.  That way if there's a very small change, I could just replace the .cs file instead of compiling again and posting the .dll file again.

Comment: What's the actual problem with compiling and deploying? Because you could use continuous integration, where you check your code into source control and a seperate agent compiles it and deploys it, but I don't think that's what you want. Just trying to understand the problem here. Compiling/deploying is too slow? too complicated?

Comment: The primary reason is that I want to maintain ability to debug code and post quick fixes on the server if there's any urgent need while my team is unavailable.  While we will have better systems in a few weeks (weekly releases, etc.), as of now, it would be much quicker to try a few changes directly on the server instead of making changes in local project and then posting dll on the server, since this is a sandbox system anyway.

Comment: I strongly advise against fixing bugs in production as you want. Even if it's a development server and you want to get a quick fix. Spend a bit of time and setup a CI-CD environment that will re-publish your website once you push a commit in the main or development branch... also spend some time to structure your project correctly even if it's a very tiny project consisting of a couple of pages - branches, unit tests, e2e tests etc. running github actions when you create a PR etc. - trust me this will pay off and the experience is invaluable. 

Debug on your own machine, not prod server!

Answer (score 2):

C# is not a script, you can't just run the source code without compiling (or publishing) it.

Comment: I'm using C# for coding the back-end functions (APIs).  I meant to ask if there's any way I can host those directly as code the way we host web services and those get compiled at run-time instead of posting published dlls.

Comment: "I could just replace the .cs file instead of compiling again and posting the .dll file again" -- 

I'm afraid you can't do that for ASP.NET application.

Comment: We used to do that before with ASP.NET Website project. So if it's doable - it definitely is one way or another. Last resort would be to run a system service watching for file changes to recompile the source. Although I'd go for real CI-CD in this case.